# AntBuilder (groovy) with comma separated files (FileSet "include")

Tags: groovy, ant, antbuilder

I am using Groovy dsl in a Jenkins script where I am passing the "include" parameter value to Ant FileSet.

```
def ant = new AntBuilder()
def scanner = ant.fileScanner {     
  // grab ALL files requested to be run
  fileset(dir:"/jenkins/workspace/aJob") {
        def selectedFiles = params["testSuite"]
        include(name:"$selectedFiles")
  }
}
```

It works if `params["testSuite"]` is a single expression to select file, e.g.

> **/tests/*.java

It fails (appears to me that Groovy is unable to understand that value as-is) to find the files if `params["testSuite"]` is specified as

> **/tests/test1.java, **/tests/test1.java

However, to Ant, both the above values are correct.

Can someone tell me how I can make this work?

Comment: Have you tried just comma `,` or just space ` ` instead of comma space `, ` as a separator?

Comment: I tried with both. None worked. FileScanner finds 0 (zero) files.

Comment: Does `**/tests/*.java,**/tests/*.java` work? Might be there aren't any matching files with `test1.java` (which I hope is an example, and not an actual Java source filename)

Comment: That does not work either. I suspect a syntax problem is likely. The file names and the FileSet paths are correct, and I verified that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the comma separated one in the wrong level.  You're putting it in an `<include>` element instead of the `includes` attribute (see the [doc page](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html)).

So to use the comma method you'd do

```java
def ant = new AntBuilder()
def scanner = ant.fileScanner {
  // grab ALL files requested to be run
  def selectedFiles = params["testSuite"]
  fileset(dir:"/jenkins/workspace/aJob", includes: "$selectedFiles")
}
```

And actually, you can use comma, space, or comma space (even though the doc doesn't mention that).

Comment: Great! That works perfectly. I had realized that I had to use "includes", but was not sure about the syntax. Thanks!